# SQL Query execution in SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Finding issue in achieving below problem in `SSIS`.

I have a variable in `SSIS` `@Select` which is initialized with a SQL task in SSIS as below.

`@Select='Select column1, column2 from tableName'`, like a dynamic select query, now I want to Execute `@Select` variable(which should execute select query inside it) to return the full result set in a separate SQL task I have tried it like below but not succeeded.

```
Declare @Query Varchar(2000)

SET @Query=? // here ? will store the select query in @Select variable

EXEC (@Query) // executing to return result set??
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute a dynamic select query in SSIS then use an Execute SQL Task and edit the task.

Set the ResultSet option to Full Result Set if you are expecting multiple rows and Single Row for only one row. Add your DB connection name to the connection property and ensure that it is in the list of connection managers and configured correctly. You can set the SQLSourceType to Variable and specify the variable you want to use below that. Although using the Direct Input option is just as good where you specify your SQL Statement. Now set the variable you want the ResultSet to write to in the Result Set tab, which is in the left column of the task editor. you can even specify the parameter variable you would like to use in the Parameter Mapping tab.

You can click on Build Query to see if your query works. Hope this helps and let me know if I missed anything :)

Comment: Thanks @Ryno Mayer this is what i exactly wanted.

Comment: However can you please help me how can we create and map variables at run time in SSIS??

Comment: Variables can only be added in Design mode, variables can be assigned values at runtime by adding them in the Result Set tab and setting ResultSet to single row. [link](http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/) this might help.

Comment: Sad then i have to switch to store procedure now :(

Comment: i think the best thing would be to execute a stored procedure from ssis